# python create and append txt file using loops and variables

Tags: python

I have created variables that I need to drop into txt files.  I am not having any success. My program will create the header information, but stops writing to the file after that.   The top loop is my "Order Header" and the machines loop is my "Order Detail".  I've tried debugging, and looking at it from every angle.  I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  The program is writing all of the text files and appending for the XHORNO and XHCSNO. As far as troubleshooting, I have tried print statements (`print "header"`  `print "detail"`, and `print "machine"` ) to verify that the code was hitting each loop as expected.  That effort resulted in the correct output.  However it won't write the detail loops variables to file.

```
for k, v in atlantic_billing.iteritems():
    # print "header"
    #CREATE XHORNO
    XHORNO = str(digits + counter)
    print XHORNO
    with open(XHORNO + ".txt", 'w') as order:
        XHCSNO = k
        machines = v
        #create order header information
        order.write(XHORNO+"\n")
        order.write(XHCSNO+"\n")
        line = 1
        counter = counter + 1
        for machine in machines :
            try:
                XDORNO = XHORNO
                XDORSQ = line
                line = line + 1
                XDITD1 = ranpak_dict[machine]['MODEL']
                XDITD2 = ranpak_dict[machine]['SN']
                XDCAVC = ranpak_dict[machine]['TOTAL']
                order.write(XDORDQ + "\n")
                order.write(XDITD1 + "\n")
                success.append(machine)
                lines = lines + 1

            except :
                issues.append(machine)
                problems = problems + 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best guess with the given information... each loop is getting down to:

```
lines = lines + 1
```

And then throwing a `NameError` because `lines` is undefined (you called it `line` before). Since your `except` clause is catching *all* exceptions, the program quietly adds that entry to `problems` and moves on.

This is a good example of why you should try to be as specific as possible about what errors you catch in your `except` clauses.

*Edit: ...but I suppose it should still have written the lines to the file at that point? So... possibly still more information needed. But definitely narrow down your `except` to make it easier to troubleshoot.*

Comment: `lines` is actually a variable created above the initial loop.  However, I removed it just to verify it wasn't causing the issue and that didn't fix it.  Thanks for the suggestion on the except clause, though!  I will keep that in mind moving forward.

Comment: @AlliDeacon Start by eliminating the `except` block altogether. If the error you get is one you'll need to catch, then add the block back with that single type of error. If you get more errors you need to handle, add them to the clause one by one. Eventually, hopefully you'll get to the actual error that's causing problems.

Comment: Thanks so much!  I learned something new!  I didn't realize that I could use except this way.  I found the error, and corrected it.  All is working like it should.